# Was /were Priya and Susan in the library yesterday

Tags: grammar

Was/were Susan and Priya in the library yesterday?

Comment: Which subject pronoun would you use to substitute "Susan and Priya"? "She" or "they"?

Answer (score 1):

They are 2 people. In this case the past tense of the verb be takes the plural form: "were".

According to https://www.thefreedictionary.com/were :

> **were**
>
> > the plural form of the past tense (indicative mood) of be

Answer (score 1):

You would say **were** because it is just the question form of the sentence:

> Susan and Priya were in the library yesterday.

The reason it is *were* there is because there are two subjects (Susan and Priya) as opposed to just one (therefore you use the plural agreement).

Answer (score 0):

There are two people (plural) so 'were' is used

If talking about one person, was is used. For example:

> Ram, the engineer and manager, was sick.